# Call numpy ravel and include an interger multi-index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 4-dimensional array. I am going to turn it into a 1-dim array. I use numpy ravel and it works fin with the default parameters.

However I would also like the positions/indices in the 4-dim array.

I want something like this as row in my output.

x,y,z,w,value

With x being the first dimension of my initial array and so on.

The obvious approach is iteration, however I was told to avoid it when I can.

```
for i in range(test.shape[0]):
    for j in range(test.shape[1]):
        for k in range(test.shape[2]):
            for l in range(test.shape[3]):
                print(i,j,k,l,test[(i,j,k,l)])
```

It will be to slow when I use a larger dataset.

Is there a way to configure ravel to do this or any other approach faster than iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) with `sparse=False`, combined with [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to build the array. `np.indices` provides the first `n` columns, and `np.concatenate` appends the last one:

```
test = np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 5, 4, 2))
index = np.indices(test.shape, sparse=False)  # shape: (4, 3, 5, 4, 2)
data = np.concatenate((index, test[None, ...]), axis=0).reshape(test.ndim + 1, -1).T
```

A more detailed breakdown:

1. `index` is a `(4, *test.shape)` array, with one element per dimension.
2. To make `test` concatenatable with `index`, you need to prepend a unit dimension, which is what `test[None, ...]` does. `None` is synonymous with `np.newaxis`, and `Ellipsis`, or `...`, means "all the remaining dimensions".
3. When you concatenate along `axis=0`, you are appending `test` to the array of indices. Each element of `index` along the first axis is now a 5-element array containing the index followed by the value. The remaining axes reflect the shape of `test`, but besides that, you have what you want.
4. The goal is to flatten out the trailing dimensions, so you get a `(5, N)` array, where `N = np.prod(test.shape)`. Thats what the final `reshape` does. `test.ndim + 1` is the size of the index +1 for the value. `-1` can appear exactly once in a reshape. It means "product of all the remaining dimensions".

Comment: Thanks, great solution. Don't completely understand how you can concatenate and reshape, but I need to learn more.

Comment: @BorutFlis. See the update. I added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Hard to imagine the multiple dimenstions.